# How to get all refinements defined in a module?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

In ruby, is it possible to get a list of all refinements defined in a module?

For example, given this:

```
module MyRefinements
  refine String do
    def foo
      "#{self}_foo"
    end
    def trim
      "this is not a good example, but demonstrates an override"
    end
  end
end
```

How can I get an array like this: `[:foo, :trim]`?

Comment: would you like to get it from a Module file parser or within the code itself?

Comment: @mabe02, I would prefer to be able to get it from within the code itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

A bit ugly, but working. You should know module name and class of refine:

```
module MyRefinements
  refine String do
    def foo
      "#{self}_foo"
    end
    def to_str
      "this is not a good example, but demonstrates an override"
    end
  end
end

# Provide module name and class (type)
def get_refinements mod, type
  ret = []
  mod.module_eval do
    refine type do
      ret = self.ancestors
        .select{|el| el.to_s.include? "refinement" }
        .map{|el| el.instance_methods(false)}.flatten
    end
  end
  ret
end

module Test
  p get_refinements(MyRefinements, String)
end
```

Output is:

```
#=> [:to_str, :foo]
```

Comment: I tried to play around with your idea. Actually it seems to be consistent even when you are refining more types. Would you consider a good option to provide an hash such as `REFINED_METHODS ={}` where you set the type as key and the methods refined as values (what your are printing just _flatten_) that would be accessible as `MyRefinements::REFINED_METHODS`?

Comment: Is it possible to get this from outside of the refine block?

Comment: Very nice! I believe you could simplify a bit: `refined_methods = []; MyRefinements.module_eval do; refine String do; refined_methods = instance_methods(false); end; end; refined_methods #=> [:to_str, :foo]`. If you add the line `puts "self=#{self}, ancestors=#{ ancestors }"` it would print `self=#<refinement:String@MyRefinements>` and `ancestors=[#<refinement:String@MyRefinements>, String, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`.